# Finding the volume of an $n$-dimensional simplex (recursion)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, riemann-integration

I want to find the volume of an $n$-dimensional simplex, i.e. determine
\begin{align*}
\sigma _{n} = \int_{A_{n}}^{} \mathrm{~d}\mu , \quad A_{n}= \{ ( x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid 
\forall i\colon x_{i} \geqslant 0, \quad x_{1} + \ldots+ x_{n} \leqslant 1\}
.\end{align*}
I came up with the following informal computation:
We consider
\begin{align*}
A' = [0, 1], \quad A_{x_{1}} = \{ ( x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n})\mid x_{2} + \ldots+x_{n} \leqslant 1- x_{1}\}
\end{align*}
and conclude
\begin{align*}
\sigma _{n}
&= \int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{A_{x_{1}}}^{} \mathrm{~d}\mu ( x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}) \right)\mathrm{~d}x _{1}
\\
&\stackrel{(*)}{=} \int_{0}^{1} \sigma _{n-1} (1 - x_{1})^{n-1}\mathrm{~d}x _{1}
\\
&= \sigma _{n-1}\left[-\frac{1}{n}( 1 - x_{1})^n\right]_{0}^{1}
= \frac{\sigma _{n-1}}{n}
.\end{align*}
Solving this recursion we find
\begin{align*}
\sigma _{1} = \int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{~d}x _{1} = 1 \implies \sigma _{n} = \frac{\sigma _{1}}{n!} = \frac{1}{n!}
.\end{align*}

How I can formalise the $(*)$ step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval can be iteratively splitted up, i.e. first you have
\begin{align*}
  &A' = \{ ( x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n-1})\mid x_{1} + \cdots + x_{n-1}\leqslant 1\}
  \\ 
  &A_{(x _{1}, \ldots, x_{n-1})} = \{ x_{n}\mid x_{n} \leqslant 1 - x_{1} - \cdots - x_{n-1}\}
\end{align*}
yielding
\begin{align*}
\int_{A_{n}}^{} \mathrm{~d}\mu 
&= \int_{A'}^{}\left( \int_{A( x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n-1})}^{} \mathrm{~d}x _{n} \right)\mathrm{~d}\mu ( x_{n-1}, 
\ldots, x_{1})
\\
&= \int_{A'}^{} \int_{0}^{1 - x_{1} - \cdots - x_{n-1}} \mathrm{~d}x _{n} \mathrm{~d}\mu ( x_{n-1}, \ldots, 
x_{1})
.\end{align*}
Continuing this procedure with $A'$ one ends up with
\begin{align*}
\sigma _{n} = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1 - x_{1}} \cdots \int_{0}^{1 - x_{1} - \cdots - x_{n - 1}} \mathrm{~d}x _{n}
\cdots \mathrm{~d}x _{2}\mathrm{~d}x _{1}
.\end{align*}
To compute this, we write
\begin{align*}
f _{n}( r) = \int_{0}^{r} \int_{0}^{r - x_{1}} \cdots \int_{0}^{r - x_{1} - \cdots - x_{n - 1}} 
\mathrm{~d}x _{n}\cdots \mathrm{~d}x _{2} \mathrm{~d}x _{1}
.\end{align*}
This allows us to establish a recursion, namely
\begin{align*}
  f _{n+1}( r) &= \int_{0}^{r} \cdots \int_{0}^{r - x_{1} - \cdots - x_{n}} \mathrm{~d}x _{n+1}\cdots 
\mathrm{~d}x _{1}
= \int_{0}^{r} f _{n}( r - x_{1})\mathrm{~d}x _{1}
\\ 
&= -\int_{r}^{0} f _{n}( x_{1}) \mathrm{~d}x _{1}
= \int_{0}^{r} f _{n}( x_{1}) \mathrm{~d}x _{1} 
\\[5pt] 
&\implies f _{n+1}'( r) = f _{n}( r)
.\end{align*}
With the base case $ f _{1}( r) = r$ this yields
\begin{align*}
f _{n}( r) = \frac{r ^{n}}{n!}
\implies f _{n}(1) = \frac{1}{n!}
.\end{align*}